# Terraform helm set value of type array

Tags: parsing, escaping, terraform, kubernetes-helm

When I set an array value for a helm_release resource from my TF code like below:

```
set {
    name  = "ObjectIds"
    value = "{${join(",", local.rbac_config.group_oid_list)}}"
}
```

My TF Plan shows the value being passed like whats shown below:

```
+ set {
      + name  = "ObjectIds"
      + value = "{"Id1-xxxxxxxxxxx,Id2-yyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyy,Id3-zzzzzzzzzzzzzzzz"}"
    }
```

**Why I need the format to be like this?**

When the helm chart is installed manually from the command line using `helm install`, it throws an error if I specify `--set ObjectIds={Id1-xxxxxxxx,Id2-yyyyyyyy,Id3-zzzzzz}`

**Helm Error**: `Error: This command needs 2 arguments: release name, chart path`

**Fix:** It works just fine when I specify `--set ObjectIds={"Id1-xxxxxxxx,Id2-yyyyyyyy,Id3-zzzzzz"}`.
So I want the Terraform code to parse the value as `value = "{"Id1-xxxxxxxx,Id2-yyyyyyyy,Id3-zzzzzz"}"` instead of `value = "{Id1-xxxxxxxx,Id2-yyyyyyyy,Id3-zzzzzz}"`

**Things I have tried:**

**1. Doesn't works:**

```
set {
    name  = "ObjectIds"
    value = "{\"${join(",", local.rbac_config.group_oid_list)}\"}"
}
```

**Failue/Error** : TF Plan parses the value as

```
+ value = "{\"Id1-xxxxxxxx,Id2-yyyyyyyy,Id3-zzzzzz\"}"
```

**2. Doesn't works:**

```
set {
    name  = "ObjectIds"
    value = format("\"%s\"", join(",", local.rbac_config.group_oid_list))
}
```

**Failue/Error :** TF Plan parses the value as

```
+ value = "{\"Id1-xxxxxxxx,Id2-yyyyyyyy,Id3-zzzzzz\"}"
```

Any suggestions how do I get this working?

Comment: What's wrong with the second one? This is how you escape double quotations.

Comment: The \ is being passed too IDK why. I tried with \\\ too. @Marcin

Comment: Have you tried applying it? Construct that you want `"{"Id1-xxxxxxxx,Id2-yyyyyyyy,Id3-zzzzzz"}"` is incorrect. You have to escape quotation as in the second example of yours.

Comment: I tried applying what you said (the 2nd one) , Go the following error:
`Error: YAML parse error on akt.rbac/templates/somefile.yaml: error converting YAML to JSON: yaml: line 18: found unexpected end of stream`

Answer (score 5):

I know it is old question, but when you have variables you can use dynamic set:

```
dynamic set {
    for_each = var.sample_array
    content {
      name = "object[${set.key}]"
      value = set.value
    }
  }
```